# Slight confusion on voltage calculation

Tags: voltage, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

I have this circuit, and I'm trying to understand how the solution arrived on an equation involving the open current voltage V_th, in particular, the bottom equation: Vth = V_12ohm - V_3ohm.

[image: circuit]

Where did the equation come from? Was it KVL? If so, I'm confused on the signs of the components; shouldn't we be adding them rather than subtracting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your image and adding the loops and showing where I'd start the equation using a little dot in the lower left-hand corner of each loop:

[image]

Using [passive sign convention](https://spinningnumbers.org/a/sign-convention.html) (which appears to me to be opposite to what you are being taught) for loop \$I_a\$, I get:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+12\:\text{V} -6\:\Omega\left(I_a\right) - 12\:\Omega\left(I_a-I_b\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

(The above is exactly the same as you provided. I'm just using a different convention than you did, I think.)

As they say, \$I_b=-2\:\text{A}\$, given that the current source is pointed oppositely. So it does follow that \$I_a=-\frac23\:\text{A}\$.

So, looking at the \$12\:\Omega\$ resistor we'd say that the top end is \$V=V_b+12\:\Omega\cdot I_a-12\:\Omega\cdot I_b\$. That's in keeping with the signs.

Then, looking at the \$3\:\Omega\$ resistor we'd say that the right side (no current in the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor) says that \$V_a=V-3\:\Omega\cdot I_b\$. That's also in keeping with the signs.

Putting it all together gives:

$$V_a=V_b+12\:\Omega\cdot I_a-12\:\Omega\cdot I_b-3\:\Omega\cdot I_b=V_b+22 \:\text{V}$$

So \$V_a-V_b=22 \:\text{V}\$. Which is what you were asking about.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I may need to repeatedly refer to your answer for a while given that I am not used to this convention.

Comment: @Niko Understood. The convention is opposite to what I gather you've been using. I apologize for that. But it is the more-often used convention, these days, I believe. So I think you should spend a little time getting familiar with it. Best wishes!!

Answer (score 0):

Think of it not as subtracting, but as adding a negative voltage.

Take the 12\$\Omega\$ resistor for instance, since you're using clockwise  loops in loop 1 you would label it with + on top, but in loop 2 it would be labeled with - on top. When you do loop 1 you therefore need to add \$12I_a\$ and subtract \$12I_b\$ (really you're adding \$-12I_b\$).

It would help you to draw out the circuit, draw an arrow for each loop, and label the polarities in each loop. The polarities are the tricky part of KVL/KCL. I would recommend finding some examples and practice.

Comment: I am aware about the different polarities for different loops. But I'm still confused as to why the 3 ohm resistor has a negative voltage whereas the 12 ohm resistor was positive for the same loop.

Comment: Ah, at that point they're figuring Vth, which is the voltage across the 12 ohm resistor minus whatever voltage drop there is across the 3 and 2 ohm resistors. Since the 2 ohm has no current through it it's voltage is 0, so it's just the voltage across the 3 ohm being subtracted. It's a different loop than the 2nd one, it's the 12, 3, 2 ohm resistors and Vth.